# How can I get a number with a thounds separator on top?

Tags: sql, sql-server, digit-separator

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM table A
```

let's say the result is `8689`. How can I convert it to `8'689` on the SQL Server?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in sql server? Why not format the values in your application?

Comment: i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Try This way:-

```
select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money,  count(*)),1),'.00','') 
from table_name
```

and be sure you really need this approach, formatting the application is the usual and best as SqlZim said.

**UPDATE:-**

for setting the separator on top, Try the next:-

```
select replace( replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money,  count(*)),1),'.00',''),',','''')
from table_name
```

Comment: i need the separator on top

Comment: @anna, I had updated my answer, waiting your feedback.